# Laravel 5.8 use subdomain as API endpoint beside domain.com/api

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I have a production server with some API's endpoints. I just want to make a more pretty system moving all API calls from `domain.com/api/v1/xxxxxx` to a subdomain like `api.domain.com/v1/xxxxxx`

By now, I just create the subdomain at cPanel: api.domain.com
then point that subdomain to the `public_html` folder of laravel (I did the trick for `public -> public_html` rename )

Then add the route mapping domain in api.php:

```
//SubDomain Mapping
Route::group(['domain' => 'api.bachecubano.com'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
        Route::get('categories', 'Api\AdController@get_categories')->name('api_get_categories');
    });
});
```

And try it at `api.domain.com/v1/xxx` but give me error. So the working solution is `api.domain.com/api/v1/xxx`

But that its too ugly, I need to remove the second `/api/` url parameter.

How do I tho this?

PS: Put the subdomain mapping to `public_html/api`, but that obviously crash with error 500.

My mind says to me that the solution might be in .htaccess file, but In don't know much about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the default `api` prefix by deleting `prefix('api')` from the `mapApiRoutes()` method in your RouteServiceProvider, like below:

**App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php**

```php
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    // prefix('api) has been deleted

    Route::middleware('api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
}
```

As for the api subdomain, I would just park it on top of the main domain.  Then you don't have to worry about what directory it's pointed at.

Comment: Yes, I think about it, and it´s the correct answer, but I just think about mapping or internal redirect with `.htaccess` 

Answer (score 0):

Using .htaccess in apache, you can add this.

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.(bachecubano.com)$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%1/api/$1 [L,R]
```

It redirects any call on the api subdomain to the domain/api internally.