# How to route my API endpoints in Laravel as api.domain.com instead of domain.com/api

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain, restful-url

I am building a RESTful API for the first time using Laravel 5.8.

I want my `routes/api.php` to point to `api.mysite.test`

My question is very similar to [Laravel 5.8 use subdomain as API endpoint beside domain.com/api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532949/laravel-5-8-use-subdomain-as-api-endpoint-beside-domain-com-api?answertab=active#tab-top)

The accepted answer to the question above is

> As for the API subdomain, I would just park it on top of the main domain. Then you don't have to worry about what directory it's pointed at.

I don't understand it very well, but I want to be able to use `mysite.test` as a web interface, presenting the API.

So far I removed the prefix from `mapApiRoutes` in `RouteServiceProvider.php` and tried to concatenate the subdomain

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {

        Route::domain('api.'.url('/'))
             ->middleware('api')
             ->namespace($this->namespace)
             ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
```

My `routes/api.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::apiResource('resources', 'ResourceController');
```

In `/etc/hosts`:

```
192.168.10.10   mysite.test
```

In `.env`:

```
APP_URL=mysite.test
```

In `config/app.php`

```
'url' => env('APP_URL'),
```

When I try to reach my resource

`GET api.mysite.test/resources` results in `Could do not get any response`

Also bothers me that

```
>>> url('/')
=> "http://localhost/mysite.test"
```

instead of `mysite.test` as I stated in `.env`

Comment: The change you did in the mapApiRoutes was what you should do. Try to add 192.168.10.10   api.mysite.test in your hosts file, as well

Comment: when I add ```192.168.10.10 api.mysite.test``` to ```/etc/hosts```
for GET api.mysite.test/resources I get HTML response with status '404 not found'

Comment: If I hardcode ```Route::domain('api.mysite.test')``` in mapApiRoutes works fine, but why ```url('/')``` generates ```"http://localhost/mysite.test"```? It's wierd?

Answer (score 1):

I got myself sorted.
So first as [Mauro Baptista](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5999683/mauro-baptista) pointed in the comments all subdomains have to be added to `/etc/hosts`. In my case

```
192.168.10.10   mysite.test
192.168.10.10   api.mysite.test
```

It turns out there's no problem that they share the same IP address.

The second problem was my URL generation in `RouteServiceProvider.php`
`Route::domain('api.'.url('/'))` does not produce valid URL.
Instead the proper syntax is `Route::domain('api.'.parse_url(config('app.url'), PHP_URL_HOST))`
Credit to [Adding a Subdomain to Your Laravel Application](https://pineco.de/adding-a-subdomain-to-your-laravel-application/)

Comment: `Route::domain(env('app_domain')) `does also work if you add "app_domain" and assign api.mysite.test under .env